Cannot run deja-dup on Ubuntu
I am trying to use deja-dup on my Ubuntu desktop 22.04 in order to backup to a Windows server. But I get this error message:
Failed to mount Windows share: Invalid argument

i created a share folder on my windows server called server1. when i enter into properties>sharing: the network path is \UNC\server1 and there is a permission set to allow everyone full control.
on my ubuntu desktop, when i enter my backup>preference. i selected Network server and my network location is set to smb//UNC/server1. same with my folder server1. i have tried to use my ip and it keeps showing that error

Can you browse to the share successfully in your file manager on the Ubuntu system? In other words, if you copy the network location out of the box in deja-dup and paste it into the address box in your file manager, does it work?

Yes, I can but I can't access any folder on the windows server. I get "unable to access location ubuntu 22.04: failed to mount windows Share: invalid arguments.

Do you get that message in the file manager or in deja-dup? You already said that you got that message in deja-dup. If you got that message in the file manager, I would say the answer to  my question is no, you cannot browse to the share.

I get it on Deja-dup and also in the file manager when i try to access to folder.

OK, so the problem is not deja-dup, it is the way your share is setup or the way you are accessing it. If you can't browse to it in the file manager, you can't backup to it in deja-dup. Unfortunately I don't know anything about Windows sharing so I can't really  help here.

What version of WIndows? Win10, Win11, ...?

windows server 2022

You aren't going to be able to access that server using a smb://hostname/share-name since there is no smbv1 on that server which is the "invalid argument" Use smb://hostname.local/share-name or smb://ip-address/share-name.

I tried using both my hostname and my Ip, but it still returns the same error. I added "min protocol = NT1" within the global section of my "smb.conf file" and ran "Sudo systemctl restart smbd" after to enable Smbv1

@Stephen_esu if that fixed it, please post an answer. Answering your own question is fine here.

No, it's not fixed. just stating what i tried to do next. but still getting the same error.
